# Accessing the child of a group with owslib in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, group-layer, ows, owslib

How can I iterate a layer group with owslib in QGIS in a script? If is not possible, are there alternatives?

Here is a sample code of what I'm trying to achieve:
`2,5,8` has `1` as parent.

```py
from owslib.wms import WebMapService
wms = WebMapService('https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/wms/wms', version='1.1.1')
list(wms.contents)) #prints wms layers,not the groups also [['MOD14A1_M_FIRE', 'MOD14A1_E_FIRE'...]
# the above is listing only the children not the parents
# I want to iterate also the parent with 0->1->[2,5,8] within a script
   
img = wms.getmap(layers=['1'], #this is not working bcs a parent obviously
                 srs='EPSG:6343',
                 bbox=(708542, 460329, 731172, 493289),
                 size=(100, 100),
                 format='image/tiff')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of how the structure of your content looks like? I checked this ows https://neowms.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/wms/wms and there are layers which one can fetch them with your code block and RGB or greyscale which style to be chosen https://i.imgur.com/JvJERNJ.png

Comment: @Nil the issues isn't that the qgis isn't showing me the layers in WMS Data Source Manager, the issue i have is to iterate **with the script** through the layers group, and choose a group(all childrens) or a single layer(child) based on some filter, like in your example: https://imgur.com/a/iQSC36o